# how to call / run multiple python scripts from batch file in window xp / 7

Tags: python, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule run multiple pythons using batch file.

For example there are my python files that I want to schedule run them on the daily basis

```
D:\py\s1.py
D:\py\s2.py
```

now how can I combine these two files into a .bat, so that I can schedule run these two file using `python.exe` (`C:\python27\python.exe`) at the same time.

Thank you

Comment: Well, there is the option of calling them natively from a parent Python script too.  But even if you don't want to do that, this is a pretty rudimentary batch script.  Are you having specific problems with environment or something, or do you just want a ready-made custom solution done for you?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Method 1**: Bat file.

If you have python in the PATH Environment variable:

```
start python D:\py\s1.py
start python D:\py\s2.py
```

Else literal path

```
start C:\python27\python.exe D:\py\s1.py
start C:\python27\python.exe D:\py\s2.py
```

Note that this will not wait for a return from either execution. Note, do not forget to add quotations around the path strings if they contain spaces or special characters.

See `start /?` for more help and options.

**Method 2**: Two different Scheduled Tasks

Create two separate scheduled tasks that start at the same time each calling python to run one of the scripts.